# Целесообразность вложенных div'ов при верстке

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Учебы и эксперимента ради решил сделать простой новостно/блого-сайт. Ну, никогда с нуля не писал сайты, а тут дёрнуло. Нужно мне это для дальнейшего развития. Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой выбора. Хочу сделать вещь такую: хедер (шапку с банером и на банере справа окошко с логином и паролем (это, к слову, уже сделал. Да вообще всё сделал, просто вопрос все равно интересует)), потом основною часть сайта, которая состоит из двух колонок из дивов - слева навигация, справа контент из новостей, ну и футер со всякими копирайтами, счетчиками и прочей лабудой.

Как сделал я - я создал один огромнейший див, общий, так сказать, "подложку". На нём я создаю див хедер со всякими отступами (хедер весь резина в ширину), в диве хедер я создаю ещё один див прилепленный справа - это форма логина. Далее создаю основную часть - делаю див лэфт и райт. Диву лэфт присваиваю ширину, к примеру, 300 пикселов, див райт - резина на оставшееся место. В диве лефт я делаю ещё один див навигации, в котором, в свою очередь делаю составной блок (заголовок, контент). Ну и справа в подобном духе все. Ну и потом ниже этих двух идет футер, тоже резина.

Так вот вопрос: нужно ли обязательно делать вот такие вот всё время все больше и больше вложенные дивы, или можно сразу изначально делать без вот этого огромного дива, к примеру, потом без большого дива основной части, т.е. отдельно сам по себе блок слева для навигации и отдельно справа для контента, ну и потом футер тоже отдельно потом?

Comment: На практике уровень вложенности получается намного глубже, 10-20 уровней вполне нормально для сайта средней сложности. Если использовать CMS, то множества вложенных дивов избежать не получится никак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внешний общий div - вполне себе нормально. Обычно ему дают класс **.container**. Такому контейнеру удобно выставлять стили связанные с позиционированием. Например минимальну и максимальную ширину, центрирование. Иногда такой div нужно создавать, чтобы обернуть все, кроме подвала, чтобы последний прижать к низу хитрым способом каким-нибудь. Бывает, что надо добавить фон этому контейнеру, а не body.

Дивы обертки, для подряд идущих колонок, тоже вполне себе нормально. Если вы делаете колонки при помощи обтекания, то перед закрытием такого div`а это обтекание хорошо бы сбросить. Таким div`ам оберткам обычно дают класс **.wrapper**.

Вообще за пару лишних div`ов вас, конечно, никто ругать не будет, если вам с ними удобнее и вы думаете, что так логичнее.

Анализируйте больше чужих работ. Если видете толковый сайт, не ленитесь смотреть на разметку firebug`ом :)

P.S. полурезиновые макеты (с фиксированным сайдбаром и тянущимся контентом) сложнее, чем могут показаться. Попробуйте, например, использовать обтекание и сброс обтекания внутри тянущейся колонки. Или сделать содержимое в одно слово внутри этой колонки. Смотрите, что происходит с фоном этой колонки. Я очень долго не мог справиться с такими краш-тестами :). Мне [вот такой вариант разметки](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala24.html) нравиться. Там без "лишних" div`ов тоже не обошлось.

Answer (score 2):

Все, конечно, зависит от структуры макета. Если это резина, то, думаю, можно обойтись без большого общего дива. Но если это не резина то общий блок для сайдбара и контента нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Всем огромное спасибо. Файрбагом пользуюсь на всех подряд сайтах на которые захожу, смотрю, как и что у них, и на многих по-разному, поэтому и возник вопрос. Но в целом я понял, спасибо, полезную информацию дали.